# Query for many-to-many relationship

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got a database designed like:

**t_relationships**

- id (unique)
- relationship_uuid
- actor_uuid

**t_actor**

- id (unique)
- actor_uuid
- name_or_whatever_doesnt_matter

The relationship table has many actors with one `relationship_uuid`.

I'm having problems with efficient query that will give me all the actors in a relationship with a given actor.

For instance, if `actor table` have entries `[1,1,cat], [2,2,dog], [3,3,tree], [4,4,box]`

and `relationship` has `[1,1,1], [2,1,2], [3,1,3], [4,2,1] [5,2,4], [6,3,2], [7,3,4]`.

What's the best way to find out who is in a relationship with a cat?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `id` columns. You can just drop them. A join is what you are looking for

```
select ar.name
from t_actor a
join t_relationships r on r.actor_uuid = a.actor_uuid
join t_actor ar on ar.actor_uuid = r.relationship_uuid
where a.name = 'cat'
```